# How do I access an ngModel's FormControl from a Directive/Component

Tags: angular

I'm not talking about the value of the ngModel but rather the FormControl associated with that model. What I want to do is add an entry to that FormControl.

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input',
})
export class InputDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        debugger;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // how to I access the FormControl from here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out its as easy as injecting `control: NgModel` into the constructor.

`constructor(private element: ElementRef, control: NgModel) {}`

edit: complete directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel]',
})
export class InputDirective {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef, ngModel: NgModel) {
        const formControl = ngModel.control as FormModel;

        formControl.name = this.element.nativeElement.name;

        this.element.nativeElement.onblur = () => {
            if (formControl) {
                formControl.isBlurred = true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: can you demonstrate how NgModel gets passed to the directive? i.e. `<div input [NgModel]="ngModel"`>` ... that's how I would imagine. and then use the `@Input` import in the directive

Comment: I added the complete code. The reason this works is because of the `ngModel` selector

Answer (score 0):

To have access to the ngModel form control of an input element in a **Attribute Directive** you can inject the **NgControl** to the directive's controller and Angular DI framework will provide the closest form control instance:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[input-directive]',
})
export class InputDirective implements OnInit {
   constructor(private control: NgControl, private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtfguu) for an example.

To provide the form control to a **Component** you can use a **template variable** which will be assigned with the ngModel FormControl instance and pass it as an input to the component, like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>    
<example-app [name]="ctrl"></example-app>
```

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cej2q8) for an example.